# Angular2: Most efficient way of using helper functions in components

Tags: angular, import

This component is straight from the angular2 docs.

The only modification I have added is the import of a function from another file into this component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

// IMPORTING HELPER FUNCTION FROM LIB
import {
    showOrNot
} from '../helpers';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    templateUrl: 'hero-detail.component.html'
})

export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    // USING IMPORTED HELPER FUNCTION FROM LIB
    showOrNot: showOrNot;

    constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ) {}

    @Input()
    hero: Hero;

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.heroService.getHero(id)
                .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the template for the component a simple show or not based on the return of the showOrNot function.

```
<div *ngIf="showOrNot()">
    <h1>{{hero.name}} details!</h1>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

I can appreciate this code and it's neatness, this above component only uses includes the functions is has been told to and not the whole lot.

But, is there a way to optimize this? To use this code in the template I not only need to import it into the component but also reference it in another class method within the component.

is there a way to call the helper class's method from the template directly without having to route it through yet another function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a helperService, inject it into the component, and then use it in your template.

```
  constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location,
        private helperService: HelperService,
    ) {}

<div *ngIf="helperService.someHelperFunction()">
    <h1>{{hero.name}} details!</h1>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
    <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

To better understand it would be nice to know what your function need (inputs) and what it should do.

Service solution is a neat one.